# Is this a Schwartz function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I would like to know whether this function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
$$f(x):=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{(k!)^2}}$$ is a Schwartz function?

By applying the chain-rule it is clear that $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and more or less obviously we have that $|x^a f(x)| \rightarrow 0$  for $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$. But what about derivatives? How can I show that

$|x^{a} f^{(\beta)} (x)| \rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ or is this false?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: The denominator here is the Bessel function of order zero evaluated at $i 2x$ if that's any help.

Comment: Alternate approach: the denominator is Bessel function $I_0(2x)$, and there are known asymptotics for that (and its derivatives) as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{(k!)^2},$$so $$g'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2kx^{2k-1}}{(k!)^2}.$$It's clear that $$\frac{2k}{(k!)^2}\le\frac2{((k-1)!)^2}\quad(k\ge1),$$so $$|g'(x)|\le2|x|\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2(k-1)}}{((k-1)!)^2}=2|x|g(x).$$This shows that $$|f'(x)|\le2|x|f(x).$$Similarly for higher derivatives (because for example $(2k)(2k-1)/(k!)^2\le c/((k-2)!)^2$).